# two dimensional Hilbert space basis -clarification

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

For a programming project I need the basis of a two dimensional (complex) Hilbert space. Unfortunately, I am not a mathematician and need help.

I think a basis is $\vec{b_1} = \begin{bmatrix}  1 \newline  0 \end{bmatrix}$ und $\vec{b_2} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \newline 1\end{bmatrix}$. Is this correct?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Could you specify what is the Hilbert space? The basis only makes sense if the Hilbert space is the set of $2\times 1$ matrices with entries from $C$.

Comment: @seeker Thanks, it is a $2 \times 1$ matrices with entries from $\mathbb{C}$